# visual studio 2022 excluding Android Manifest

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm new here. i am testing visual studio for mac 2022. i am opening a xamarin project made in vs 2019 for mac. whenever I open it it deletes the android manifest and creates a new one. am i missing something?

Comment: I believe it is generating the manifest based on the options you have selected in the Android project dialog

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this occurs without any previous action from me

Comment: I didn't say you did anything.  I'm saying that the all of the properties in the manifest are mapped to options in the Android project dialog, and those are used to generate the file.  Regardless, if you are testing a new version of VSMac and have a problem, you should report it back to the VSMac team.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by updating the Android.csproj file with the configuration property groups created in a new VisualStudio 2022 Android project;

here's an example of one of the configuration tags I changed:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">  
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
  <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
  <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
  <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
  <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
  <MandroidI18n />
  <AndroidTlsProvider>btls</AndroidTlsProvider>
</PropertyGroup>
```